# what's the best way to test GWT widget's view's implementation

Tags: gwt, gwt2

There have been a lot of talk on MVP and how it seperate the presentation logic from the view's implementation. These designs are good but I still have a question unsolved regarding to widget.

To develop a widget, (or possibly many small widgets included in a typical website), specially those designed with UIBinder, I found it very difficult to test (or just simple display) a widget's view implementation. The obviously way is to add it manually to an entry point class and display the widget only, which works but seems very tedious if the widgets are getting more and more.

So the question is: what's the best way to just simply display a widget when it's being developed? and possibly to interact with it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to display the Widget and interact with it in order to test it you need a [functional testing too](http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html#FUNC)l.

One such tool is [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).